# General formula for adding columns in dataframes that depends on exisiting columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes as below.

dataframe1 =

```
   ID   D   F   G   Q
0   T1  1   3   4   5
1   T2  2   3   2   6
2   T3  4   7   7   8
3   T4  5   6   7   8
```

dataframe2 =

```
    ID  Q   G   F   
0   T10 10  54  44  
1   T12 20  45  43  
2   T11 30  45  65
```

I want to add a column by the following method.

```
dataframe1['sum'] = dataframe1.D + dataframe1.F + dataframe1.G + dataframe1.Q
```

This will give `sum` column for `dataframe1`, but if I apply the same formula for `dataframe2`, it will throw an error as there is no column `D` in `dataframe2`.

I want a general formula that will give `sum` even if `D` is not present(in that case just ignore `D` and consider those remaining columns according to formula and compute `sum`).

How can I do that in a single line code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersection of needed columns with the dataframe columns will yield the columns the dataframe has.

```
needed_columns = ['D', 'F', 'G', 'Q']

def has_columns(x): return list(set(x.columns) & set(needed_columns))

df1['sum'] = df1[has_columns(df1)].sum(axis=1)
```

Gives,

```
   ID  D  F  G  Q  sum
0  T1  1  3  4  5   13
1  T2  2  3  2  6   13
2  T3  4  7  7  8   26
3  T4  5  6  7  8   26
```

Also, If you change the dataframe,

```
df2['sum'] = df2[has_columns(df2)].sum(axis=1)
```

Gives,

```
    ID   Q   G   F  sum
0  T10  10  54  44  108
1  T12  20  45  43  108
2  T11  30  45  65  140
```

Answer (score 3):

`df.sum` will add all numeric columns and ignore columns with `object` datatype

```
df["sum"] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: This is assuming that you need all the columns in a dataframe to create sum column.

Comment: @Vishnudev by looking at OP's data, it seems OP wants the sum of all numeric columns as he is asking for generic solution